# Finding the name of labels based on text inside its name

Tags: vb.net

I’m not really sure this is possible but it would be helpful: I have quite a large grid of labels and would like to change the visibility of them based on words inside their names, for example finding a list of labels which all contain “Twentytwo” in their name and setting their visibility to false

Comment: Please can you explain more what you have in front of you? "large grid of labels" what does it mean? The user control grid and there are label-controls (Or TextBlock) on that grid with text property "Twentytwo" in this text? Then, you can use the parent of the labels and iterate though all children. As soon as the type matches the label you can identify the text and decide to setup the Visiblity to Collaped or visible.

Comment: Sure can by large grid I was describing the set up that I have for the labels they’re not in a grid, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I have the labels inside a panel in Visual Basic(.vb) they’re all 35 by 35 and I used the location property in the properties panel to line them up to create a large “grid” of labels, I’m not quite sure if that answered all your questions hope it did

Comment: I’m using the Visual Basic GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [Control.GetNextControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol?view=net-5.0):

```
    Const textToSearch = "Twentytwo" 'Text to search

    Dim c As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
    Do Until c Is Nothing
        'Check if c is label and its name contains "textToSearch"
        If TypeOf c Is Label AndAlso c.Name.Contains(textToSearch) Then
            c.Visible = False 'Hide this label
        End If
        c = Me.GetNextControl(c, True)
    Loop
```

If you want to search "*Twentytwo*" in the label text and not in its name, replace `c.Name.Contains`with `c.Text.Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your labels are all in one container, perhaps a Panel.

Further, let's assume you that you want only the specified labels to have `.Visible = False`, so the visibility is simply whether or not the label's name contains the given string.

You can select for controls of a particular type, so that there's no need to check the type of the control before using it, like this:

```
Sub SetLabelVisibility(container As Control, namePart As String)
    container.SuspendLayout()

    For Each lbl In container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        lbl.Visible = lbl.Name.Contains(namePart)
    Next

    container.ResumeLayout()

End Sub
```

And you would call it with

```
SetLabelVisibility(Panel1, "Twentytwo")
```

Suspending the layout of the container while the updates to its child controls are being made is so that the display of it is done in one go.

---

Demonstration using an appropriately-sized Panel on a Form:

[image: Labels being made visible and invisible]

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim tim As New Timer With {.Interval = 1000}

    Sub CreateLabels(target As Panel)
        For j = 0 To 6
            For i = 0 To 4
                Dim lbl = New Label With {
                                    .Name = $"Label{j}_{i}",
                                    .BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond,
                                    .Text = i & j,
                                    .Location = New Point(j * 40, i * 20),
                                    .Size = New Size(38, 18),
                                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                                }

                target.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub SetLabelVisibility(container As Control, namePart As String)
        container.SuspendLayout()

        For Each lbl In container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
            lbl.Visible = lbl.Name.Contains(namePart)
        Next

        container.ResumeLayout()

    End Sub

    Sub ChangeVisibleLabels(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Static n As Integer = 0
        SetLabelVisibility(Panel1, n.ToString())
        n = (n + 1) Mod 7

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateLabels(Panel1)

        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ChangeVisibleLabels
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ChangeVisibleLabels
            tim.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Form1

    Dim tim As New Timer With {.Interval = 1000}

    Sub CreateLabels(target As Panel)
        For j = 0 To 6
            For i = 0 To 4
                Dim lbl = New Label With {
                                    .Name = $"Label{j}_{i}",
                                    .BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond,
                                    .Text = i & j,
                                    .Location = New Point(j * 40, i * 20),
                                    .Size = New Size(38, 18),
                                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                                }

                target.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub SetLabelVisibility(container As Control, namePart As String)
        container.SuspendLayout()

        For Each lbl In container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
            lbl.Visible = lbl.Name.Contains(namePart)
        Next

        container.ResumeLayout()

    End Sub

    Sub ChangeVisibleLabels(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Static n As Integer = 0
        SetLabelVisibility(Panel1, n.ToString())
        n = (n + 1) Mod 7

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateLabels(Panel1)

        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ChangeVisibleLabels
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ChangeVisibleLabels
            tim.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Form1

    Dim tim As New Timer With {.Interval = 1000}

    Sub CreateLabels(target As Panel)
        For j = 0 To 6
            For i = 0 To 4
                Dim lbl = New Label With {
                                    .Name = $"Label{j}_{i}",
                                    .BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond,
                                    .Text = i & j,
                                    .Location = New Point(j * 40, i * 20),
                                    .Size = New Size(38, 18),
                                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                                }

                target.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub SetLabelVisibility(container As Control, namePart As String)
        container.SuspendLayout()

        For Each lbl In container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
            lbl.Visible = lbl.Name.Contains(namePart)
        Next

        container.ResumeLayout()

    End Sub

    Sub ChangeVisibleLabels(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Static n As Integer = 0
        SetLabelVisibility(Panel1, n.ToString())
        n = (n + 1) Mod 7

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateLabels(Panel1)

        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ChangeVisibleLabels
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ChangeVisibleLabels
            tim.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```