# create function for sender object handler

Tags: vb.net

how do i create a function for a sender as object click? I tried something, but it didn't work out.

```
 Private Function functionName(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If sender.checked = True Then
            For i As Integer = 2 To 14
                If i <> 2 Then
                    Dim cbClubs = DirectCast(Controls.Item("cbBtt" & i & "detrefla"), CheckBox) 'Clubs
                    cbClubs.Checked = False
                End If
            Next
        End If

    End Function

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        functionName(cbBtt2detrefla, sender)
    End Sub
```

Comment: If sender is an object it will have to be cast to the correct type before using.  Looking at your usage the arguments don't match(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Comment: As mentioned above you'd cast the sender (object) to the type of control that it actually is. Example: `Dim chkBox =DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)`  assuming the sender is a checkbox

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put that "If" statement in the For Loop.  Just start the loop at i = 3.

Comment: In the first "If" statement, The "= True" is superfluous.

Comment: Your functionName signature does not match the call to it in youtr Button1_Click delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put some order in this code.

```
Private Function functionName(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   '...
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    functionName(cbBtt2detrefla, sender)
End Sub
```

Why are you using `e As EventArgs` in functionName(...) declaration? It's never used, so u can delete it:

```
Private Function functionName(ByVal sender As Object)
```

In functionName you are evaluating `sender.Checked` (a tip: you can use `If sender.Checked` instead of `If sender.Checked = True`): why not to define sender as CheckBox, instead of Object?

```
Private Function functionName(ByVal sender As CheckBox)
```

Now, let's see the for Loop:

```
For i As Integer = 2 To 14
    If i <> 2 Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

You are evaluating i from 2 to 14, but you don't want to do anything if i = 2. Why not to start the for loop from i=3? It's faster and better.

```
For i As Integer = 3 To 14
    '...
Next
```

Another thing: `functionName()` doesn't produce an output, so it should be a `Sub`, not a `Function`.

Now, your code is:

```
Private Sub functionName(ByVal sender As CheckBox)
    If sender.Checked Then
        For i As Integer = 3 To 14
            '...
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    functionName(cbBtt2detrefla)
End Sub
```

Furthermore, if `functionName` is called only by `Button1_Click` and here it is only used with `cbBtt2detrefla`, you can avoid separating the two subs:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
    If cbBtt2detrefla.Checked Then
        For i As Integer = 3 To 14
            '...
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Last, but not least:

```
Dim cbClubs = DirectCast(Controls.Item("cbBtt" & i & "detrefla"), CheckBox) 'Clubs
cbClubs.Checked = False
```

This works only if `cbBtt3detrefla` and the others checkBoxes are directly on the form. If they are in a `Panel`, for example, you'll get a `System.NullReferenceException`. If you want to iterate on every control, you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67035641/6584029).